# How to put contents in Sencha Touch tab

Tags: android, json, twitter, cordova, sencha-touch

I am new to Sencha Touch and Phonegap. I have one html file and one js file. I want to have 3 tabs. In each tab I am putting different Twitter search result. But I don't know when to put my tweet code.

Here is my index.html file: http://pastebin.com/Nv2Jfqr4
Here is my index.js file http://pastebin.com/f9nmycBP

And here is my tweet .html file  http://pastebin.com/PPpGiZ3k

Comment: Also, you need to accept more answers that 6 out of 20 if you want people to help you.

Comment: but man i didn't got currect answer if i get currect answer than definetly i accepted it

Comment: yeah right, how about you give it a try a give us the specific errors if it doesn't work instead of waiting for the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take a look at the [Kitchen Sink](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/examples/kitchensink/) and tell us what kind of user interface component you want to put your twitter search results (probably a list) and then we'll help you achieve what you want.

Comment: yes i want to put a list and i don't need a search box i want to have three tab in each tab there is three word android iphone and blackberry in click event of each tab i am getting twitts of clikable tab's text.